# Get my location in OsmDroid not work

Tags: java, android, osmdroid, android-gps

i'm testing my app in the android emulator and the icon of position is displaied but when i try to center the map in that point the method getMyLocation return 0,0,0.
Also if i test my app in a device don't display the user's location.
This is my code:

```
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(getApplicationContext()), map);
    myLocationoverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(9);
    map.getOverlays().add(myLocationoverlay);
```

map.animateTo(myLocationoverlay.getMyLocation());

And my manifest is:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using in Wi-Fi - explore this page:
https://developer.android.com/preview/features/wifi-aware.html.
They describe to add more line code at the manifest and so on.
It'll help you using in wi-fi

Best Regard

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" was that i tested my app with Wi-Fi but ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION works only with cellular networks